# Typescript type inference without undefined

Tags: typescript, type-inference

The following code has OfficeDocument type which was inferenced from User, but userId should be number without undefined. Required doesn't work.

How can I do it? I'd like for example to get an error in calling the handleDocument function about incorrect type.

```
type User = {
    id: number | undefined;
}

type OfficeDocument = {
    userId: Required<User['id']>;
}

const handleDocument = (document: Required<OfficeDocument>)  => {
    console.log(document);
}

const user: User = {id: 10};
const officeDocument: OfficeDocument = {userId: undefined};
handleDocument(officeDocument);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by making `id` optional:

```js
type User = {
    id?: number
};

type OfficeDocument = {
    userId: Required<User>['id']
};

const handleDocument = (document: OfficeDocument)  => {
    console.log(document);
}

const user: User = {id: 10}; // Works
const officeDocument: OfficeDocument = {userId: undefined}; // Error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'
handleDocument(officeDocument);
```

Then, the `Required<>` removes the optional, and forces `OfficeDocument.userId` to be a number.

The `Required<User>['id']` is necessary because that retrieves the type of `Required<User>`, which makes all of the properties on `User` required. `Required<User['id']>`, on the other hand, makes all of the properties of `User['id']` required, which is not what is needed for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

`Required` transforms an *object type* with optional properties into one with required properties. For example:

```
type User = {
    id?: number;
}
type PopulatedUser = Required<User>;
// result:
// { id: number }
```

Using `Required` on something that isn't an object won't do anything. If you want to exclude `undefined` from a union, use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype).

```
type OfficeDocument = {
    userId: NonNullable<User['id']>;
}
```